# How to get pending transactions in ethereum using web3?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I need to calculate the nonce for successive transactions using web3js in Ethereum, but `getTransactionCount` does not return pending transactions.

Is there a way to get all transactions including both pending and completed transactions using web3js? If not web3js, is there some other way to do that??

Answer (score 2):

using web3js 1.0 you can use `getPendingTransactions`

```
 web3.eth.getPendingTransactions().then(console.log);
 >  [
     {
         hash: '0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b',
         nonce: 2,
         blockHash: '0xef95f2f1ed3ca60b048b4bf67cde2195961e0bba6f70bcbea9a2c4e133e34b46',
         blockNumber: 3,
         transactionIndex: 0,
         from: '0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b',
         to: '0x6295ee1b4f6dd65047762f924ecd367c17eabf8f',
         value: '123450000000000000',
         gas: 314159,
         gasPrice: '2000000000000',
         input: '0x57cb2fc4'
         v: '0x3d',
         r: '0xaabc9ddafffb2ae0bac4107697547d22d9383667d9e97f5409dd6881ce08f13f',
         s: '0x69e43116be8f842dcd4a0b2f760043737a59534430b762317db21d9ac8c5034'
     },....,
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)?

Following code should work. (unable to test myself at the moment)

```
var options = {
  fromBlock: "pending",
  toBlock: "latest",
  address: "0xabc123...",
}

web3.eth.filter(options, (error, result) => {
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: `filter` didn't work for me, also, is it even a function of web3? If yes, then why it isn't mentioned in this [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html)

Comment: @AbhishekKumawat my friend, the [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html) you're referring is for web3.js **v1.0** the one I've referred to was the [**web3 0.x.x**](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

Comment: Yea I figured that out. Perhaps, v1.0 has no functionality for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Atu How to do the same thing but by just listening instead of constantly polling?

Comment: @user2284570 i don't think there's a way to do that for `pendingTransactions`... afaik there's event listener for contract events

Comment: @Atu but contract events d ont happens before a transaction is mined?

Comment: @user2284570 oh i'm not entirely sure about that. But i'm guessing that they don't.

Comment: @Atu so this isn t an alternative option. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/65095482 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue# [1741](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1741), maybe you can better wait for the transactions to get cleared as a work around.

Comment: Perhaps yes, I queued transactions. Now, I wait for the receipt and then execute the next one in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script in python using web3.py to retrieve pending transactions! it's on my GitHub: https://github.com/soos3d/Retrive-and-display-pending-transactions-Web3.py. Feel free to check it out! But the main code to do that is this.

```
# retrive pending transactions hash

pending_tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
pending_tx = pending_tx_filter.get_new_entries()
```

then you can loop through the "pending_tx" variable and extract the transactions hash.