# How to listen for incoming transactions not yet mined for a single address?

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, unix-socket, json-rpc

Using OpenEthereum, which is the json rpc call allowing to do it?
I found the [`parity_pubsub`](https://openethereum.github.io/JSONRPC-parity_pubsub-module) module but I ve no idea of the parameter for getting not yet confirmed transactions.
I also found https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-pendingtransactions in the web3 module but it doesn t allows to filter transactions and the documentation doesn t explains how to use the full web3 api along OpenEthereum.

## The purpose

The aim is to frontrun transactions for arbitrage by always maintinning the highest gas price until the next block is mined.
This involve detecting competiting transactions (those targetting the same Ethereum address as mine and with a higher gas price than me) with the lowest latency as possible in order to replace them as soon as possible (either for abortting the trade or changing the gas price again). **So this exclude constantly polling for the answer as the requirement is to have the lowest number of context switches**.

Comment: At that point, I ve no idea of the language (outside it needs to be a fast language which excludes things like Python or rust) I will use in order to program my OpenEthereum client for trading although I m having a specific contract s address in mind. And that the connection to OpenEthereum will be performed over ipc.

Comment: Please do not rollback improvements to posts.

Comment: @TylerH **then, I disagree, you remove useful tags, and while I m open to it, Javascript wasn t the language I was thinking about for using the web3 library, so this can t be made a requirement though adding the relevant tag**. And for frontrunning, unix-socket connection is a requirement for using web3 instead of http which supposed to without the tag. **Your edit is not an improvement**.

Comment: You may not be aware, but web3js (the library you linked to) is a JavaScript library, so you can't use it without "using" JavaScript. If you want to use some other language, like Solidity, that's fine, but you should specify that (and apply that tag). The [tag:web3] tag is bad and being removed; you should use [tag:web3js] or the specific library tag you intend to use, instead. Do not add the [tag:web3] tag back.

Comment: @TylerH : **No** ! I was thinking about using `web3py` or `web3julia`. Same functions name, but not the same language. Ethereum and tokens is all about cryptocurrencies while being programmable of course…

Comment: If you are thinking about using web3py or web3julia, why did you link to web3js documentation? Please use the tag for the language you intend to use. And yes, Ethereum is a specific blockchain technology that can be used for (among other things) cryptocurrencies; using the [tag:ethereum] tag is good. Using the vague [tag:cryptocurrency] tag is not.